# React JS - get a variable vlaue to show up in a form field

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

For the past few days I have been trying to figure out simply how to make default text show up in a form in react. Each div has a "Recipe Title" and I need the unique recipe title for the particular div to show up in the editable field. Nothing that I have watched or read seems to reveal how to do this. Please could someone point me in the right direction?

My CodePen for this project is [here](http://codepen.io/profaneVoodoo/pen/qajKRv).

```
var GenerateRecipesFromList= React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    const defaultData = [["Spaghetti", "pasta, oil, sauce, parsely, cheese"], ["PB&J", "PB, J"]]
    const localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reclist'));
    return {
    reclist: localData ? localData : defaultData
   }
 },  

updateRecList: function (reclist) {
this.setState({ reclist: reclist });
},

overlayEdit: function() {
  var el2 = document.getElementById("overlay2");
el2.style.visibility = (el2.style.visibility === "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
},



render: function(){
 var testData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reclist'));
 if(testData === null){
    localStorage.setItem('reclist', JSON.stringify(this.state.reclist));
    }
    var currentData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reclist'));
    var rows = [];

      for(var i=0; i<currentData.length; i++){
    var thedivname = i;
     var recipetitle=currentData[i][0];
        console.log(recipetitle);
      rows.push(<div id= {this.thedivname} className="individual" onClick= {this.overlayEdit}> <span><h2>{this.state.reclist[i][0]}</h2></span> 
    </div>);
    }
  return(
    <div className="centerMe" >
      <AddButton updateRecList={ this.updateRecList } />
      {rows}

      <div id="overlay2" recipetitle="recipetitle" >
        <div>
          <form > 
            <p>Edit an existing recipe.</p>
            Recipe Title: <input type="text" name="title2" id="title2"  value={this.recipetitle}>
                {
                  // HOW DO I MAKE "Spaghetti" SHOW UP AS THE DEFAULT TEXT IN THE Recipe Title INPUT AREA WHEN I CLICK THE DIV FOR Spaghetti??????????
            }
            </input><br/>
            Ingredients: <input type="text" name="ingredients2" id="ingredients2"/><br/>
          </form>
          <p>Click here to <a href='#' onClick={this.overlayEdit}>close</a></p>

        </div>
      </div> 

    </div>
   );
  },
});

var AddButton = React.createClass({

  overlayAdd: function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("overlay");
  el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility === "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
  },

  exposeAddRecipe: function(){
      var exposeCurrentData = [];
      var userInput = [];
      exposeCurrentData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reclist'));
     var newTitle = document.getElementById("title").value;
     var newIngredients = document.getElementById("ingredients").value;

     userInput.push(newTitle);
     userInput.push(newIngredients);
     exposeCurrentData.push(userInput);
      localStorage.setItem('reclist', JSON.stringify(exposeCurrentData));
      //this.setState({ reclist: exposeCurrentData});
    this.props.updateRecList(exposeCurrentData);
     this.overlayAdd();
  },

  render: function(){
  return(
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="btnAdd" onClick={this.overlayAdd}><h2>Add a New Recipe</h2></button> 
        <div id="overlay">
         <div>
            <form > 
             <p>Add a new recipe.</p>
             Recipe Title: <input type="text" name="title" id="title">

              </input><br/>
             Ingredients: <input type="text" name="ingredients"  id="ingredients" /> <br/>
           <button type="button" className="normalBtn" onClick= {this.exposeAddRecipe}>Save</button>
           </form>
           <p>Click here to <a href='#' onClick={this.overlayAdd}>close</a></p>

          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
      );
     }
  });

var Footer = React.createClass({
    render() {
    return (
      <footer>
        <div id="containerfooter">
          <p>Written by <a href="http://codepen.io/profaneVoodoo/full/dXBJzN/">John Gillespie</a> for FreeCodeCamp Campers. Happy Coding!</p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    );
  }
  });


var MyApp = React.createClass({  
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className = "mainDiv">
          <div className="titleDiv">
         <h1>Recipe Box</h1>

           <GenerateRecipesFromList />
           <Footer />
          </div>        
        </div>
    );
  }, 
}); 

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyApp />,
  document.getElementById('Recipes')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create a new state variable `recipe`. Then in your onClick function where you add rows pass the `recipe` name as

```
rows.push(<div id= {this.thedivname} className="individual" onClick={this.overlayEdit.bind(this, recipetitle)}>
```

After that in the overlayEdit function set the state variable recipe to be the value as

```
this.setState({recpe: value})
```

and then in the form make use of this state variable to set the input as

```
Recipe Title: <input type="text" name="title2" id="title2" value={this.state.recepi}/>
```

hope this helps

**Complete code**

```
var GenerateRecipesFromList= React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      const defaultData = [["Spaghetti", "pasta, oil, sauce, parsely, cheese"], ["PB&J", "PB, J"]]
      const localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reclist'));
      return {
        reclist: localData ? localData : defaultData,
        recepi: ''
      }
  },  

  updateRecList: function (reclist) {
    this.setState({ reclist: reclist });
  },

  overlayEdit: function(value) {
    this.setState({recepi: value})
      var el2 = document.getElementById("overlay2");
    el2.style.visibility = (el2.style.visibility === "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
  },



  render: function(){
    var testData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reclist'));
    if(testData === null){
        localStorage.setItem('reclist', JSON.stringify(this.state.reclist));
        }
        var currentData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reclist'));
        var rows = [];

          for(var i=0; i<currentData.length; i++){
        var thedivname = i;
         var recipetitle=currentData[i][0];
            console.log(recipetitle);
          rows.push(<div id= {this.thedivname} className="individual" onClick={this.overlayEdit.bind(this, recipetitle)}> <span><h2>{this.state.reclist[i][0]}</h2></span> 
        </div>);
        }
      return(
        <div className="centerMe" >
          <AddButton updateRecList={ this.updateRecList } />
          {rows}

          <div id="overlay2" recipetitle="recipetitle" >
            <div>
              <form > 
                <p>Edit an existing recipe.</p>
                Recipe Title: <input type="text" name="title2" id="title2" value={this.state.recepi}/>
                <br/>
                Ingredients: <input type="text" name="ingredients2" id="ingredients2"/><br/>
              </form>
              <p>Click here to <a href='#' onClick={this.overlayEdit}>close</a></p>

            </div>
          </div> 

        </div>
      );
    },
});

var AddButton = React.createClass({

      overlayAdd: function() {
        var el = document.getElementById("overlay");
      el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility === "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
      },

      exposeAddRecipe: function(){
          var exposeCurrentData = [];
          var userInput = [];
          exposeCurrentData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reclist'));
         var newTitle = document.getElementById("title").value;
         var newIngredients = document.getElementById("ingredients").value;

         userInput.push(newTitle);
         userInput.push(newIngredients);
         exposeCurrentData.push(userInput);
          localStorage.setItem('reclist', JSON.stringify(exposeCurrentData));
          //this.setState({ reclist: exposeCurrentData});
        this.props.updateRecList(exposeCurrentData);
         this.overlayAdd();
      },

      render: function(){
      return(
        <div>
          <button type="button" id="btnAdd" onClick={this.overlayAdd}><h2>Add a New Recipe</h2></button> 
            <div id="overlay">
             <div>
                <form > 
                 <p>Add a new recipe.</p>
                 Recipe Title: <input type="text" name="title" id="title">

                  </input><br/>
                 Ingredients: <input type="text" name="ingredients" id="ingredients" /> <br/>
               <button type="button" className="normalBtn" onClick={this.exposeAddRecipe}>Save</button>
               </form>
               <p>Click here to <a href='#' onClick={this.overlayAdd}>close</a></p>

              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
          );
         }
  });

var Footer = React.createClass({
    render() {
    return (
      <footer>
        <div id="containerfooter">
          <p>Written by <a href="http://codepen.io/profaneVoodoo/full/dXBJzN/">John Gillespie</a> for FreeCodeCamp Campers. Happy Coding!</p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    );
  }
  });


var MyApp = React.createClass({  
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className = "mainDiv">
          <div className="titleDiv">
        <h1>Recipe Box</h1>

           <GenerateRecipesFromList />
           <Footer />
          </div>        
        </div>
    );
  }, 
}); 

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyApp />,
  document.getElementById('Recipes')
);
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKzjEW)